# Translation of sentence and why is a kereba used in this sentence?

Tags: translation, relative-clauses

In the first verse of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJ8ViGoaV6k) song, they say:

> 最寄り駅の改札抜ければ　いつもよりちょっと勇敢なお父さん

Is this even a full sentence? My translation would be:

> When passing through the ticket gate at the nearest station as usual, comes out(?) a little more brave father.

Is this translation correct and also, I thought that when saying when the tara form is being used? Isn´t kereba more like if he passes through the ticket gate?

Comment: いつもより is not "as usual"

Comment: "More than usual" then?

Comment: No, it is not a sentence; It is only a line in a song lyric.  Good thing you seem to have noticed it.  For it to be a sentence, it needs to contain a verb phrase in the second half as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is about working day-in and day-out for your family and so they use the kereba in sense that *if or when* he is able to through that gate just that one more time, then the father becomes a little bit braver as he fights the world (at work).  The assumption that is that it's sometimes hard to face the world.

Using your translation as a base, I'd say something like:

> If/When he passes through the ticket gate at the nearest station, daddy will come out a little bit braver.

Comment: If ~~ よりも When ~~ とか Once ~~(一旦～すれば) になるんじゃないでしょうか。「トンネルを抜けると(≂抜けたら)雪国だった」と同じ「～たら」「～ると」。

Comment: @chocolate 両方も解釈できるんじゃないかな？追加させていただきます！